# Creating an Alexa conversational skill using AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop an Alexa skill that works as an everyday conversation.

**For e.g -** 

Me - Alexa, what time is it?

Alexa - It's 9.00 pm

Me - Can I reach airport by 10 p.m ?

Alexa - Yes if you take route XYZ

..

and so on

Essentially, instead of
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3CD2.jpg), I need the skill to function as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnds2.jpg)

Is there any extra piece of code that I need to build to keep the session alive?

**Note** - I am using AWS lambda function with Python backend to develop this skill.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking for help with here. Are you stuck on something specific? Do you have any code to post? Also I'd recommend checking out [this python Alexa Skills Kit](https://github.com/johnwheeler/flask-ask) library

Comment: To clarify things, I have a skill that answers only 1 question (on the basis of intent) and then it sleeps off. 
So if i want Alexa to continuously answer my questions on the basis of context, how do I that?

E.g -
Me - Alexa, schedule a meeting for me
Alexa - What time do you want to schedule the meeting?
Me - 5 pm on 7/7/2017

Comment: @TyloBedo I have edited my question to clarify my problem. Thank you.

Comment: [Alexa Custom Skills Response Format](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#response-format) Set `"shouldEndSession": false` ? Posting your code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue the session, use **ask** responses instead of **tell** responses. A tell response will cause the skill to stop listening to the user.

You'll have to keep a few variables in state to persist data between intents, but besides that, you can treat each of those intents the same as your first.

Best of luck!

Comment: hi, my responses are in json format which i return from a function --> output speech is string O/P

    return {
        'outputSpeech': {
            'type': 'PlainText',
            'text': output
        },
        'card': {
            'type': 'Simple',
            'title': "SessionSpeechlet - " + title,
            'content': "SessionSpeechlet - " + output
        },
        'reprompt': {
            'outputSpeech': {
                'type': 'PlainText',
                'text': reprompt_text
            }
        },
        'shouldEndSession': should_end_session
    }

Comment: Take a look at the documentation [here](https://alexatutorial.com/flask-ask/responses.html#telling-with-statement) on the difference between a **question** and a **statement**. My guess is you're using statements, which end the session, when you want questions, which keep the session going.

Comment: I am using AWS lambda function and my code is written in Python. The link that you have shared is useful but it uses Flask module in Python.

Comment: I see, I had assumed you were using Flask. What SDK documentation have you been following, then?

Comment: I am following this [link](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#response-format)